# Построение диаграмм

Tags: windows-7

Нужно построить диаграмму классов, диаграмму вариантов использования, диаграмму деятельности, диаграмму последовательности.

Посоветуйте в построить? Какаю прога нужна, что корректно работала под Win 7?

Comment: вам не на этот форум с вашим вопросом

Comment: Если вопрос про диаграммы UML, то можно попробовать Microsoft Office Visio. Уже плохо помню термины, так что от вас нужно уточнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rational Rose / Rational Software Architect

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на бесплатный https://plantuml.com/. Есть онлайн - https://www.planttext.com/, есть отдельное java приложение, а также плагины для разных IDE.

Удобство в том, что сами диаграммы задаются в текстовом виде (а значит их хорошо хранить в системе контроля версий) типа:

```
@startuml

title Relationships - Class Diagram


class Dwelling {
  +Int Windows
  +void LockTheDoor()
}

class Apartment
class House
class Commune
class Window
class Door

Dwelling <|-down- Apartment: Inheritance
Dwelling <|-down- Commune: Inheritance
Dwelling <|-down- House: Inheritance
Dwelling "1" *-up- "many" Window: Composition
Dwelling "1" *-up- "many" Door: Composition
@enduml
```

А программа генерирует при этом диаграмму:

[image: диаграмма классов]